# Optomizing page turning in UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using xcode 4.3.1 and created an app using File -> New -> Project -> Page-based application.

In the DataViewController I created a webView and implemented this viewWillAppear:

```
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
          [self.webView loadHTMLString:[self.dataObject description] baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
    }
```

This creates the desired functionality, however it is a bit slow because the webview does not begin loading until it becomes visible. 
I'd like to find a way to load the previous and following webviews before they are visible so that I can get a smoother page turning effect.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a web view in a navigation based (master-detail) app, (starting a blank project and making navigation controllers myself). In my Web View Controller class, I've loaded the web view in viewDidLoad, and have added the navigation to push and pop view controllers:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view duration:0.6 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                    animations:^{
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:NO];
                    }
                    completion:NULL];
```

In this way, I have the page curl transition done, and then the data loaded in the web view, and I can handle the animation transition time with `duration`. Hope this helps you, too.